# Binding to images (with absolute path) in library

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a music player with access to the music library. I want to support cover images stored alongside the tracks, for example:

- AlbumFolder/

  - Track1
  - Track2
  - **Cover.jpg**

I have the absolute paths for these cover images stored and converted to `Uri` objects on my view-models. I tried to bind these to `Image`s in XAML using `UriSource` but the images remain blank. I also tried to bind to `Source` using a converter from the Uris to `BitmapImage` with similar results. I don't get any exceptions nor binding errors in both cases.

I know I can preload the images myself and create the `BitmapImage`s from `StorageFile`s but I'd be *recreating* the caching system already in place. Do you have any suggestions as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a Uri protocol in Windows Store applications for accessing local paths, AFAIK they work only for [resources on web, in application package and in application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

Probably the best you can do is to create `BitmapImage` in your view model based on local path. Something like this should work:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filepath);
var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

Comment: What about caching though? As far as I understand, when using `Image` with `Uri` the system takes care of loading/destroying the related resources. I want to avoid loading all of the (potentially large amount of) images  into memory all at once in the view model but I don't know a better way of doing it.

Comment: @ChrisGuterrez The only way I can think of to take advantage of that would be to copy the images to application local state and reference them from there using `Uri` syntax.

Comment: Well thank you for the help, I ended up doing lazy loading with the above code which works beautifully.